# Number of rational points $(a,b)$ on the circumference of a circle with centre as $(\pi,e)$

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, conic-sections, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

What is the number of rational points $(a,b)$ (a point is considered to be rational if both $a$ and $b$ are rational) on the circumference of a circle with center as $(\pi,e)$?

My line of reasoning is as follows:-

The equation of the circle can be written as:

$$(x-\pi)^2+(y-e)^2=r^2$$

where $r = \sqrt{(a-\pi)^2+(b-e)^2}$

Now clearly $(a-\pi)$ and $(b-e)$ are irrational individually as $a,b$ are both rational.
But can the sum of their squares be possibly rational? At first I thought maybe not but then taking an example,

$$\sqrt{(\sqrt2)^2+(\sqrt2)^2}=2$$

which is kind of the same form $(\sqrt{(Irr)^2+(Irr)^2})$ but the value turns out to be rational.

So, how would I determine the number of rational points on the the circumference? How do I know if the radius of this circle turns out to be rational or irrational??

My book says the answer is "atmost one". I can't really visualize why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rational points on a circle with centre as $(\pi,e)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991207/rational-points-on-a-circle-with-centre-as-pi-e)

Comment: @MichaelHoppe No it really doesn't. It says atmost two, my book's answer says atmost one, and some other sources say infinite. I cannot get a definitive answer

Comment: Look at the answer of Wojowu to the question linked above by Michael Hoppe. A definite answer of "at most 1" would mean the question of linear  independence of $e$ and $\pi$ over $\mathbb Q$ would be answered in the postive. It seems not have been a solved problem 1.5 years ago. I would assume any result in that direction would be relatively widely known in this stackexchange.

Comment: What sources say that there can be an infinite number?

Comment: @md2perpe my mistake, it was not really this question, but it said the following..."Prove that if a circle has an irrational radius it has infinitely many rational points on it." Isn't that also the case here?

Comment: @Techie5879. Yes, but that cannot be true. Consider a circle with center at $(0,0)$ and having a rational point $(a,b)$ on it. Then its radius $r$ satisfies $r^2 = a^2 + b^2 \in \mathbb{Q}.$ But not all irrational numbers are a square root of a rational number.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes $\pi$ and e are transcendental, right?

Comment: @Techie5879. Correct.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2233412/305759

Comment: @AshishAhuja That is not relevant to this question, as here pi and e are transcendental, not irrational, and that proof isn't valid here